# IE 10 . Attr not binding with Click Evenet

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I am creating an application and I have issue wit IE 10 . In IE 10 the the captcha text is showing first time, but when I am clicking on refresh captcha button it is not working. Fo my guess it is ATTR which is not working.
Here is my JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    Login.initialise();
});
var Login = (function(){
    var login = function(){
        var data = Util.serializeForm("#loginform");
        var request = {
                        "ssoid":data.userName,
                        "password":$("#password").val(),
                        "captcha" : data.textCaptcha
                    };
        $( "#loginform" ).submit();
    };
    var loginFormReset = function(){
        console.log("loginFormReset");
    };
    var refreshCaptcha = function(e){
        if(e){
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        $('#captchaImage').attr(
            'src',Util.getContextPath()+'/RegisterCaptchaController'
        );

    };
    var init = function(){
        refreshCaptcha();
        $("#btnLogin").click(login);
        $("#btnLoginReset").click(loginFormReset);
        $("#refreshCaptcha").click(refreshCaptcha);
        $("#refreshCaptchaTop").click(refreshCaptcha);
    };
    return{
        initialise:init
    }
})();
```

The first time it is rendering properly. the second time on clicking on Refresh button it is not working . Working fine with Chrome

Comment: Can you set up an example? What is `Util` in your case? Any errors in your console?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, the "benefits" of IE...You need to set the `src` to null and then set the new value. In other terms, this:

```
$('#captchaImage').attr(
  'src',Util.getContextPath()+'/RegisterCaptchaController'
);
```

...should become:

```
$('#captchaImage').attr('src', null);
$('#captchaImage').attr(
  'src',Util.getContextPath()+'/RegisterCaptchaController'
);
```